# "she’s often all there is to every scene"

Tags: meaning

*In the end, the formalism of “Stations of the Cross” wouldn’t work at all without the work of van Acken, a very talented young lady who’s not only in every scene, she’s often all there is to every scene.*

Source: http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/stations-of-the-cross-2015

I am really not sure what the film reviewer wants to say by the phrase "she’s often all there is to every scene". Does it mean that the strong performance of the actress monopolizes all the viewer's attention?

Comment: The author should probably have written "often all there is to **a** scene" rather than "to **every** scene".  "He often had the only goal in every game" makes no sense.

Comment: @TRomano I don't think the indefinite article has the same sense. She's in every scene, and (her performance) is often the only worthwhile part of **each** (of those) scene(s).

Comment: @ColleenV:  the same problem occurs with **often** plus **each**.  "He often had the only goal in each game" makes no sense either.

Answer (score 1):

"...she’s often all there is to every scene. “#5” is just a profile shot of Maria in confession, something that would terrify some young actresses..." (from the review) would seem to indicate that she is acting without support in some scenes, although I could also see the connotation that she does give a strong performance.